Delete files after pressing no in batch file UAC prompt
I have a SFX zip with files and a batch inside that auto-starts after extraction. The batch starts by attempting to elevate priviliges to the batch using the get admin code below.
Works fine, have used it for a long time. But now I need it to do something extra.
The SFX, upon execution, caches the files in C:\Windows\Temp. Some of the files are sensitive in content, used during the remainder of the batch file processes to set up installations, copy files etc. At the end of the batch file, the files are deleted.
However, it dawned on me that if a user presses no at the UAC prompt, the batch doesn't run so the files remain in the cache!
I decided to try and insert the file deletion in the admin code after the user presses no.
But because that part is windows shell, I cant see a way to capture that they pressed no.
"%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
DEL file1.txt
DEL file2.txt
DEL file3.txt
exit /b

"%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
 exit /b
 DEL file1.txt
 DEL file2.txt
 DEL file3.txt

After a long time trying having the extra lines in various places I got close to trying them before and after the exit /b. However it still deletes the files if you press YES.
I also tried removing the exit /b so it carries on running the admin code and triggering the deletion because admin wasn't gained, I expected that ELEV wouln't resolve at the end so tried this.
"%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
:gotPrivileges
setlocal & cd /d %~dp0
if '%1'=='' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1
    DEL file1.txt
    DEL file2.txt
    DEL file3.txt
)

I know some might comment that even if this can be done, cancelling the batch mid way through will leave the files there. Yes, but at least this is something, and I need to see if, how I can do this now.
Utlimately I need the admin code to not immediatley shutdown if the user presses no so it can delete the 3 files in the cache, THEN closing.
I thought it would be easy but hours later I need to call upon the experts once again. Thanks for any advice in advance.
:getadmin
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:init
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set cmdInvoke=1
set winSysFolder=System32
set "batchPath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )
:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO:
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
if '%cmdInvoke%'=='1' goto InvokeCmd 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
goto ExecElevation
:InvokeCmd
ECHO args = "/c """ + "!batchPath!" + """ " + args >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\cmd.exe", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
:ExecElevation
"%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
exit /B
:gotPrivileges
setlocal & cd /d %~dp0
if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Can you not create a self extracting archive which itself requires elevation. That way, you need not elevate anything else as they'd inherit the elevated status. Also a normal user does not generally have standard access to %SystemRoot%\Temp, their temporary file location is in a subdirectory of their own profile parent.

the file will be left with admin staff to do self installs, packaged up this way to reduce lots of steps to a one click affair, can check sfx making tool for admin, still interested in seeing it can be added to the admin prompt code?

Admin staff, which I assume you mean users whose accounts are allocated to the Administrators group, still do not by default have direct access privileges to %SystemRoot%\Temp. Being a member of the Administrators group, and having an elevation token, is not the same thing, (which you have already implied that you know, because you wouldn't need to raise privileges at all).

for context, same sfx has been used for years, given to IT staff to install, without issue. now has different files and a need for the said deletion.

If the same file has been used for years, why would 1. Your end users choose not to elevate when prompted? 2. Even if having done so, decide to search a relatively inaccessible temporary location for some leftover files afterwards. I'd also say that there should be a schedule or routine in place to clean up unnecessary leftover files, especially from common temporary locations. It appears to me as if you are trying to hide something from your end users, in whom you have distrust, and choosing the wrong way of going about it.

they aren't my IT Staff, third party, who will no doubt save the sfx in a library where it could be clicked on by anyone. I need the files to delete on completion of sfx or cancellation. I plan to roll out this out to my staff as an option and they will ask what happens if they click no is our special file still somewhere . I want to say no.

If they were worried about their file, why on earth would they click on no? What about creating an sfx, which extracts the initial batch file and another 'protected' sfx containing their 'special' files? This 'nested' sfx is only extracted upon the end user having positively accepted the elevation prompt.

@echo off
if "%1" equ "elev" goto elev
if exist %temp%\iselevated.tmp del %temp%\iselevated.tmp >nul
mshta vbscript:Close(CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute("cmd.exe","/c"+Space(1)+"call"+Space(1)+"""%~f0"""+Space(1)+"elev","","runas",1))
timeout /nobreak 1 >nul
if exist %temp%\iselevated.tmp (
    echo User clicked Yes on the UAC prompt!
    echo There is an elevated process running!
    echo Aborting Cleanup...
    pause
    exit /b
)
echo User clicked No on the UAC prompt!
echo No new elevated process was spawned!
echo Attempting to clear cached files...
rem DEL file1.txt
rem DEL file2.txt
rem DEL file3.txt
pause
exit /b

:elev
icacls "%~f0" /setintegritylevel HIGH >nul
cd /d "%~dp0"
if not exist "%~dp0" exit /b
echo. > %temp%\iselevated.tmp
echo Running elevated
rem change "runas",1 to "runas",0 to make the window invisible
rem (admincode goes here)
rem ???
rem DEL file1.txt
rem DEL file2.txt
rem DEL file3.txt
pause
exit /b

